# Custom Query by Author field and meta

Tags: wp-query, author

Have a CPT with custom field "size" valued "big" or "small" and Author with custom radio field "gender". Author can be "Man" or "Woman". 
Need query posts if, for example, author is "man" and filed "size" is "big".
Try something like this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'size',
        'value'   => 'big',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    )
  )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This show posts with key value "big" from all authors, but how add author with key "gender" valued "man" to this query?

Answer (score 0):

By adding another array

```
   $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'size',
            'value'   => 'big',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'gender',
            'value'   => 'male',
            ),
      )

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is

1. Create a list of users that match your search criteria

```
    $user_query = get_users( [
        'fields'        => 'ID',
        'meta_key'      => 'gender',
        'meta_value'    => 'male',
    ]);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($user_query); echo '</pre>';
```

2. Create a custom query of your custom post type where you also specify the author field:

```
    $my_custom_query = new WP_Query([
    'author__in' => $user_query,
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key'     => 'size',
            'value'   => 'big',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ]
      ],
    ]);
```

That should be it. ;-)